# How to determine where code spends a lot of time in a kernel space (system calls)

Tags: c++, c, performance, unix, system-calls

I noticed that  10% my code run is system space. However I do NOT know which system calls. I suspect, though, it is either has to do files or timestamps.

Is there a tool to figure out which system calls are the culprits? Also, I want to know the frequency of (and location) of calls (and callee) .

I am on AS3

thx

Comment: OS? The sorts of profiling tools you have available vary greatly by OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `strace` and `truss` will help you see which system calls are taking time.  Two useful options for `strace` are:

1. `-T` to show the time spent in each system call,
2. `-c` to summarize syscall counts, calls, error counts as a table.

The two options are mutually exclusive though.

You may want a full system profiling tool, to allow you to profile the kernel in more detail.  [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) is probably the best if you have it on your platform.

By platform, here are some options:

- Linux: strace, [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/), [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/).
- Solaris: [dtrace](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/dtrace/) (the original)
- FreeBSD: [dtrace](http://wiki.freebsd.org/DTrace)
- OS X: [dtrace](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html) and [Instruments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_(application)); the latter is a graphical UI over DTrace and comes with Xcode.

DTrace can even help you profile your C/C++ code with the pid provider, e.g. see [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/dmandelin/2008/02/14/dtrace-c-mysteries-solved/).

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux have a look at strace.

If you're on one of the other Unixes see if truss is available.

Answer (score 1):

If your system has it then the **truss** command should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If it is 10% then [try this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) for 30 samples. You will see the exact calls on ~3 samples, maybe 2, maybe 4.

Answer (score 0):

Again on Linux, you could try the **oprofile** profiler.  Make sure you have debug symbols available for libc and the kernel (many distributions have these on separate packages).  It profiles entire systems, not (just) single processes.  I've gotten valuable information from it.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris, you can use dtrace.