# What tool do you use to metric performance?

Tags: c, linux, performance, performance-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your favorite profiling tool (for C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663/whats-your-favorite-profiling-tool-for-c)

Instead of do it directly inside the C code, I want a some tool to do it for me. e.g, given some C code, it returns how long time it's was executed. Something like LinqPad and most client that given a SQL-query,it returns how time the query was executed in *conds.

Comment: Do you need to know how long it took in "actual" time, or how much time was spent executing each function relative to the code as a whole?  There are tools which do the latter which are likely ideal.  They tell you where your optimization effort will yield the best result overall.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux or some other os and what is the compiler?

Comment: Another duplicate: [Performance profiling on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1875167/62576), found with a search for `[c] profiling` here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You many try

1)GNU profiler **(gprof)** for function level profiling

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC2

2)For overall time statistics you may use the command,

```
time
```

[Example](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/Example-Uses-Of-The-Command-Time.htm)

3)You can also try parsing the files in **/proc**  (/proc/[pid]/stat) for a particular process,

[proc manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)